# user program interrupted with ^c

Tags: c, linux, signals

When a user program is interrupted with ^C, is the default signal handler run in user mode or in kernel mode?

If in kernel mode, which kernel subsystem invokes the default signal handler?

I could not find any reference in docs and manpages of sigaction. I was asked this question in an interview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User-level code always runs in user mode. Including the signal handlers if they have been set by that process (or its environment - C library setup routines for instance).

If there is no user-mode signal handler registered for given signal, and it is not ignored (or not ignorable/trappable as SIGKILL and SIGSTOP), the actions related to that signal (termination, core dump, suspend, resume) can be carried out entirely kernel side.

The signal delivery is mostly handled by the process scheduler subsystem in the kernel.

Comment: Of course that makes sense that the process scheduler subsystem should handler the signal delivery.A related question was that how does the kernel know which process to send the interrupt to? I am assuming that the process scheduler subsystem sends the user interrupt to the currently active process.is that right?thanks for your help.

Comment: there isn't really a "currently active process", there can be many processes currently active. if you mean "what happens when I type control-c that makes the current process in my shell receive a signal?" then ask that question - it's not a trivial process and involves the input subsystem, potentially the WM/X11, the shell... i'm not knowledgeable enough to answer that one.

Comment: The default action for `SIGINT`, killing the process, is implemented in kernelspace not userspace.

Comment: @R..: Can you link to the kernel source please? Thanks.

Comment: @Rumple: you can browse `kernel/signal.c`, function `get_signal_to_deliver`. Fatal signals without a handler will end up triggering `do_group_exit` without ever going back to userspace AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this](http://cs-pub.bu.edu/fac/richwest/cs591_w1/notes/wk3_pt2.PDF) that indicates that the handlers reside and run in user mode. There are some details in slide 8.